# how to validate "provide at least 2 tags, separated by commas" from tag textfield in php?

Tags: php, html

**HTML**

```
<h3>Tags</h3>
<input <?php echo $err_st3; ?> type="text" name="tags" id="textfield" 
placeholder="Example: tag, another tag, hello tagging" value="
<?php echo @$tagsOK; ?>">
```

**Php**

```
$tags=array();
$tagline = $_POST['tags'];
//TAGS
if(!empty($tagline)){
    $tokens = str_replace(' ', '', $tagline);
    $tags = explode(',',$tokens);
    $tags = array_unique($tags);
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        if(preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z]$/",$tag) === 0) {
            // error    
        }
        else{
            echo $count_tags = $count_tags+1;
        }
    }
    if($count_tags <= 1){
        $error[]=" - Please provide at least 2 tags, separated by commas.";
        $err_st3 = $st;
    }
    $tagsOK = implode(', ',$tags);
}
else{
    $error[]=" - Please provide at least 2 tags, separated by commas.";
    $err_st3 = $st;
}
```

When I enter the letters like "a, b", then it will be valid.

But it does not validate words like "vehicle, characters, scene"

Comment: You are matching a single character with your regular expression in `preg_match()`. Avoid using regular expressions when they are not needed, or, to put it in other terms, if your code worked; Why can I only enter tags with a-z and 0-9 characters? That is quite restrictive.

Comment: but without `preg_match()` it will add space as second tag like this `"Animal, [space]"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing preg_match check length:

```
strlen($tag)==1
```

Comment: Works... but when i enter only 1 tag.. it will add space as second tag like this `"Animal,[space]"`

Comment: if tag is word or space it will not satisfy the condition it goes to else condition